# Assign the result of a higher order function in java 8 as a method in a class

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, higher-order-functions

I was wondering if it's possible to assign the result of a function call to a class's method in Java 8. Something like this pseudocode:

```
class ClassA{
    public void method1 = higherOrder(params);
}
```

Where the resulting method1 still has its 'this' value refer to the instance when an object of ClassA is created.

Comment: Seems that you cannot. However it would be nice if you put more details including the original problem example which could be solved this way and sample implementation of `higherOrder` which makes sense here. Probably the *original* problem can be solved in Java in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. However, you can do

```
class ClassA
{
    private static final ... method1_impl = higherOrder(params);
    public void method1 (...)
    {
        method1_impl.apply (...);
    }
}
```